# Select detail from master-detail list using lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

Below is my sample data. Two companies having two employees.

```
List<Company> companies = new List<Company> 
{
    new Company
    {
        Name = "ABC Company",
        Address = "No.1 St. USA",
        Employees = new List<Employee> { new Employee { Name = "John", Age = 30 }, new Employee { Name = "David", Age = 20 } }
    },
    new Company
    {
        Name = "DEF Company",
        Address = "No.2 St. USA",
        Employees = new List<Employee> { new Employee { Name = "Michael", Age = 22 }, new Employee { Name = "Jason", Age = 27 } }
    }
};
```

I try to retrieve all employees using the following syntax:

```
var employees = companies.Select(c => c.Employees).ToList();
```

However, it gives me

> *The name 'employees' does not exist in the current context*

when I watch it at run time. My expected result is a `List<Employee>` having all 4 employees. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `SelectMany` instead of `Select`.

The error you show has nothing to do with that query. Most likely you are not in the right scope when trying to watch this variable.